# bcmwl-kernel-source not supported on kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7625-generic

Tags: networking, kernel, wifi

is there any solution for this issue? I've tried `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source` but it give me this result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-7634 linux-headers-5.4.0-7634-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-7634-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-7634-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-7634-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 336245 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Error! There are no instances of module: bcmwl
6.30.223.271+bdcom located in the DKMS tree.
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-7625-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-7625-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7625-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-7625-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You should file a bug report on launchpad for it. There's already the same for kernel 5.9 but didn't see for 5.8. Don't expect miracles for proprietary drivers on Linux. When a new kernel appears, its glue code must be adapted and this takes time and tests. Not much to do on UL SE about this.

Comment: thank you, I already report it on launchpad